# boot.ini Issue - Multi-boot System, Linux, XP and XP64 - Missing File in system32 Message

Tags: windows-xp, boot, grub, multi-boot, boot.ini

I have an interesting issue that has me stumped.  Not that I'm a computer whiz or anything.  I have a multi-boot system with two hard drives:  one drive has CentOS and Windows XP 64-bit and the other drive has Windows XP 32-bit.  CentOS grub boot loader works great, and I have it set to default to Windows.  But this is the problem.  My boot.ini file seems to be in order, yet it still gives an error if I choose the default OS (which, consequently, is XP32):

```
Windows could not start because the following file is missing or corrupt:

(Windows root) \system32\ntoskrnl.exe.
Please re-install a copy of the above file.
```

But if I choose the actual boot ID, i.e., toggle to the Windows XP Pro selection it boots just fine.  In the boot.ini file, the entry for XP 32 is the same:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Pro" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect /usepmtimer
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Pro" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect /usepmtimer
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(2)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Pro x64" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect /usepmtimer
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed boot.ini a bit and made it work.  Installed Ubuntu 10.04 in place of CentOS and adjusted the partitions.  THe 64-bit XP became the third partition on the second drive so I adjusted the boot.ini like thus:

`[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Pro" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect /usepmtimer`

`[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Pro" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect /usepmtimer`

`multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(3)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Pro x64" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect /usepmtimer`

And voila!  Everything works like a charm.